# Escape 'Balsamiq text' from question teaser?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mockups

Questions on ux.stackexchange.com sometimes contain Balsamiq wireframes (often very helpful). Some of them are included at the beginning of the posting. Looking at these postings in the questions view (https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions) sometimes causes that most of the tooltip teaser to consists of the 'Balsamiq text', like in this example:

[image]

**Q: Would it make sense to hide what I called here the 'Balsamiq text' and instead continue teasing the question text?**

Comment: Also a problem is it shows multiple newlines for posts with images

Comment: @BenBrocka Just curious - what would be the next step here?

Comment: We'd have to get a yay/nay from a stackexchange employee as they change that stuff.

Answer (score 3):

That's my question! :-)

I think the "balsamiq text" is good because it adds context to the teaser. If there were no spaces there and the asker did not put in punctuation for each line, things can get quite confusing.

I think, instead of having all that blank space and a blurb that it was created by Balsamiq, a simple place holder like `[image]` for images and `[mockup]` would be neater. Perhaps just a simple place holder `[image]` instead of having to differentiate between mockups and images would work too.

Comment: The question teaser only shows so many characters, it'd actually show more of the question's text if the balsamiq bit were removed